# How to use drools traits for multiple objects

Tags: drools

I have a set of Drools rules that work correctly if I add one fact to the drools engine, if I add two facts, the rules are only applied on the first fact. How can I make the ruleset work for multiple facts?

My traitable fact:

```
@Traitable
public class Policy {

    private String postalCode;
    private String houseHold;
    private BigDecimal grossPremium;

    public Policy(String postalCode, String houseHold) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.houseHold = houseHold;
    }
}
```

My rule set:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

declare trait PolicyWithFactors
    policy : Policy
    postalCodeFactor : Double
    houseHoldFactor : Double
end

rule rule1
when
    $f : PolicyWithFactors(policy.postalCode == "1000", postalCodeFactor == null)
then
    System.out.println("Running rule1 for " + $f.getPolicy().getHouseHold() + " and " + $f.getPolicy().getPostalCode());
    modify($f) { setPostalCodeFactor(20.0); }
end

rule rule2
when
    $p : Policy()
    not PolicyWithFactors()
then
    System.out.println("Running rule2 for " + $p.getHouseHold() + " and " + $p.getPostalCode());
    PolicyWithFactors $pwf = don($p, PolicyWithFactors.class);
    modify ($pwf) { setPolicy($p); }
end

rule rule3
when
    $p : Policy(houseHold == "single")
    $f : PolicyWithFactors(houseHoldFactor == null)
then
    System.out.println("Running rule3 for " + $p.getHouseHold() + " and " + $p.getPostalCode());
    modify($f) { setHouseHoldFactor(10.0); }
end

rule rule4
when
    $p : Policy(grossPremium == null)
    $f : PolicyWithFactors(policy == $p, $pcf : postalCodeFactor != null, $hhf : houseHoldFactor != null)
then
    System.out.println("Running rule4 for " + $pcf + " and " + $hhf);
    BigDecimal $gp = new BigDecimal($pcf * $hhf);
    modify($p) { setGrossPremium($gp); }
end

rule rule5
when
    $p : Policy(houseHold == "family")
    $f : PolicyWithFactors(houseHoldFactor == null)
then
    System.out.println("Running rule5 for " + $p.getHouseHold() + " and " + $p.getPostalCode());
    modify($f) { setHouseHoldFactor(15.0); }
end
```

The testcase that is failing:

```
public class RuleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
        Policy policy1 = new Policy("1000", "single");
        kieSession.insert(policy1);
        Policy policy2 = new Policy("1000", "family");
        kieSession.insert(policy2);
        kieSession.fireAllRules(50);
        assertThat(policy1.getGrossPremium(), is(new BigDecimal("200")));
        assertThat(policy2.getGrossPremium(), is(new BigDecimal("300")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is rule2. It will not fire as soon as there is one `PolicyWithFactors` in Working Memory.

```
rule rule2
when
  $p : Policy()
  not PolicyWithFactors( policy == $p)
then ... end
```

I haven't tried to understand all the rest, but please check whether this constraint should be present in all subsequent rules, about to match one Policy with one PolicyWithFactors.

Comment: It now calculates the first premium twice. Here's the output: Running rule2 for single and 1000
Running rule1 for single and 1000
Running rule2 for family and 1000
Running rule1 for family and 1000
Running rule3 for single and 1000
Running rule3 for single and 1000
Running rule4 for 20.0 and 10.0
Running rule4 for 20.0 and 10.0

Comment: Solved. Needed to read the values from $f.policy instead of $p